# returning wrong address from pop function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

After solving other issues with my struct, my push works as intended however my pop returns the wrong address and I'm not sure why -

```
QNode* const Q_Pop(Q* const pointerQ){

   ...       // empty check

   QNode* tempNode = pointerQ->front.next;

   pointerQ->front.next = (tempNode->next);
   tempNode->next->prev = &(pointerQ->front);

   return tempNode;
}
```

I'm fairly certain my logic for the actual removal and relinking of the stack is correct but my use of pointers and returning them is messed up.

struct -

```
struct QueueNode {

   struct QueueNode *prev;     /* Previous list element. */
   struct QueueNode *next;     /* Next list element.    */
};

typedef struct QueueNode QNode;

struct Queue {
   QNode front;    // sentinel node at the front of the queue
   QNode rear;     // sentinel node at the tail of the queue
};

typedef struct Queue Q;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have to see more code, but it seems like maybe pointerQ->front would point to the head of the queue. And you would return that instead of the next one. But, I can't tell without seeing the data structures.

Comment: I would guess that you want to pop the current object, which is `pointerQ->front`, not `pointerQ->front->next`, perhaps thats your issue.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you could provide a runnable program and told what output you were expecting. http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Weird how `pointerQ->front` is not a pointer. Based on what I know about stacks, this should be a pointer so you can change it, set to `NULL` if the queue is empty etc.

Comment: just edited it to give the struct code

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but `_QueueNode` is a reserved identifier. Agree that a compilable program is best, here.

Comment: `typedef struct _QueueNode QNode` shouldn't it be `typedef struct QueueNode QNode`?

Comment: @Havenard yeah, it was a typo i corrected it again

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using "sentinel nodes"; this is pointless and very confusing. A queue can be simply represented as a `QNode*` to the first element. It always points to the first element; if it's `NULL`, the queue is empty; if `element->next` is `NULL`, it's the last element because there isn't a next one. It's very simple to work with that.

```
struct QueueNode {
    // stuff
    // stuff
    // stuff
    struct QueueNode* prev; // this may be optional
    struct QueueNode* next;
};
typedef struct QueueNode QNode;

void push_front(QNode** queue, QNode* pushme) {
    pushme->prev = NULL;
    pushme->next = *queue;
    (*queue)->prev = pushme;
    *queue = pushme;
}

void push_end(QNode** queue, QNode* pushme) {
    QNode* node = *queue;

    if (node) {
        while (node->next) node = node->next;
        node->next = pushme;
        pushme->prev = node;
        pushme->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        *queue = pushme;
        (*queue)->next = (*queue)->prev = NULL;
    }
}

QNode* pop_front(QNode** queue) {
    QNode* node = *queue;

    if (node)
        *queue = node->next;

    return node;
}

QNode* pop_end(QNode** queue) {
    QNode* node = *queue;

    if (node) {
        while (node->next) node = node->next;
        if (node->prev) {
            node->prev->next = NULL;
            node->prev = NULL;
        }
        else
            *queue = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}


QNode* create_node_front(QNode** queue) {
    QNode* node = malloc(sizeof(QNode));
    push_front(queue, node);
    return node;
}

QNode* create_node_end(QNode** queue) {
    QNode* node = malloc(sizeof(QNode));
    push_end(queue, node);
    return node;
}

QNode* my_queue = NULL; // declare an empty queue
QNode* my_node = create_node_end(&my_queue); // create a new node, its already stored in the queue
```

I didn't test it, but it gives a general idea.

You can push with `push_front()` or `create_node_front()` (no loops, best performance) then pop with `pop_end()` to have a queue effect ([FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)), or pop with `pop_front()` to have a stack effect ([LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29)).

Comment: References aren't allowed in answers to questions that are explicitly tagged 'C' and not 'C++'.  Other that, it looks nice...

Comment: Not up to C11 — so yes, you're wrong.  References are a characteristic feature of C++ and have never been a part of C.