# Extremely difficult bug to find. Segmentation fault - C language

Tags: io, segmentation-fault, buffer, fgets

Here is a task for some experienced C users.

So I have spent a long time trying to detect this bug that is in my code. I am getting a segmentation fault at line 158, the fgets() function. I have no idea what it is. I ran valgrind and I cannot seem to understand what it says.

This is a tricky bug. If you are experienced in the C language, I would appreciate it if you can help me find out what is wrong.

I have linked the code in pastebin.com below. The code is compilable as it is:

http://pastebin.com/fJyUQBfM

Here is a text file that runs along with this program:

http://pastebin.com/JVsb9gGL

Just copy and paste all that into a txt file and run the executable file with that.

The program works for small files with limited emails, but for extremely long files with millions of emails, I get a segmentation fault at that line.

If you run valgrind a.out it will give you information about the seg fault.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `"%49[^@ ]@%49s -> %49[^@ ]@%49s"` what the hell is this?

Comment: Why is everything sized to `MAX_LEN+1`? Why don't you just make `MAX_LEN` larger by 1, so you can just use `MAX_LEN` everywhere?

Comment: @Havenard - LOL, that is my scanf conversion specifier. The 49 is to ensure the max length of the string is no more than 50 chars and there are 4 string variables it is trying to read. The format is like this: a@ex.com -> b@ex.com

Comment: @Barmar - I guess out of convention and habit. I was taught that way. Anyways that diverges from the main problem. I'll worry about style later when it matters.

Comment: Please post the valgrind output. We shouldn't have to do all the work to debug your program.

Comment: hold on I am running it

Comment: something is wrong now valgrind is saying there are no errors but I am getting a core dump still

Comment: Actually, the valgrind program is not even finishing running the code so it just sits there waiting for output to come out.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that `nodes_list` alone requires a solid chunk of 109,11 MB of memory, `edges_list` requires more 214,01 MB, and `in_degree_list` another 109,11 MB.

500 MB of memory is not a lot, but you may not be able to alloc in chunks of this size. If you were using `malloc()` it would fail. You will eventually be writing to some place you shouldn't, hence the segfault. You should use linked queues instead. Check [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193418/returning-wrong-address-from-pop-function) to know how to do that.

Also, I noticed something that isn't related to the segfault, but you have for instance:

```
Node sender;
Node nodes_list[MAX_NODE_LEN + 1];
```

And then you do:

```
nodes_list[nodes_list_index] = sender;
```

I'm not sure what you think that is happening here, but this is wrong. You cannot do that. If you want to overwrite `nodes_list[nodes_list_index]` by the content of `sender`, you should use `memcpy()`, like this:

```
memcpy(&nodes_list[nodes_list_index], &sender, sizeof(Node));
```

Or simply write directly to `nodes_list[nodes_list_index].email` instead of using `sender` as intermediate.

In addition, you declared your list so it can contain up to 550,000 pairs of senders / receivers. How big you said that list was again?

Comment: I implemented it in a different way. I overrided sender.email and used strcpy to copy the new email to sender.email and then added the sender node to the whole array.

Comment: Anyways, for this project, we are not allowed to use memory allocation, malloc, calloc, etc. and we can ONLY use arrays. So can you work around that?

Comment: The edges array can possibly hold up to 40,000 pairs of receivers+senders. I wanted to make the array large enough to accommodate large enough files.

Comment: Maybe you can store the list to a file instead of keeping it in memory. You can simply write the whole nodes to the file in binary mode, and then you can read them back one by one when you finish processing the input.