# Creating a linked list WITHOUT a global head?

Tags: c, linked-list, global, head

For an assignment dealing with recursion, we are supposed to read in the values of a file, and store the variables into a linked list. The only problem here, is for this particular assignment, we cannot have a global head. The prof. showed us in class how to locally create the head of the linked list. Only, I didn't have time to write it down. Now, trying to get a headstart on the assignment, I am stuck because I can not store things in the linked list or traverse it, because I cannot figure out how to *not* use a global head.

I usually establish the struct and head like so:

```
struct node
{
     int head;
     struct node *next;
}*head;
```

but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this without the head.

I know it may have something to do with a double pointer

```
  **head
```

Comment: A pointer to the first element of the linked list must exist somewhere, but by no means its required to exist as a global. Just pass it around as a paramenter to the functions that need it.

Comment: This answer can prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19193703/156811

Comment: How can I point to the first node without a global head though?

Answer (score 0):

```
there needs to be a 'first' pointer for the linked list.

As I understand your problem, only a global head pointer is dis-allowed. 

so put the head pointer on the stack in the main() function 
and pass the address of that pointer (not the pointer contents) 
to each of the functions that need access to it.
```

Answer (score 0):

"double pointer", "non global head pointer" . You use a local pointer for the head and a double pointer for appending, example code:

```
node * head;
node **ppnode = &head;       // pointer to head or to .next
node * pnode;
// ...
    pnode = new ...
    pnode-> ... 
    pnode->next = 0;
    *ppnode = pnode;         // set head or a next pointer
    ppnode = &(pnode->next); // advance ppnode
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the node definition be:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

It's bad style to declare variables and types in the same declaration anyway. Then in `main()` have:

```
struct node *head=NULL;
```

and proceed as you were.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample linked list without global head.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void insert(struct node **head, int val) {
    struct node *new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = val;
    if(*head)
        new->next = *head;
    *head = new;

}

void print_list(struct node *list) {
    while(list) {
        printf("%d\n", list->data);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    insert(&head, 1);
    insert(&head, 2);
    insert(&head, 3);
    print_list(head);

return 0;
}
```